# How to fix the drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm training my CSS to pass to JS, but I'm worried because I'm having some problems doing a drop-down menu.

The concept I already get, but when I put it to work, it's kind of bugging, and moving the `nav`.

```css
header {
  overflow: auto;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 250px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: roboto;
  margin-right: 50px
}

nav ul li a:hover {}

nav li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

nav li:hover li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img src="logo.png">

  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li>

        <a href="#">Menu 01</a>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu 01</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 03</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 04</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</header>
```

I sent the code with the `img` tag just to make clear the position of the stuff.  I'm also learning the stuff, so it'll probably be very bad in others monitors.

Comment: sent the code with the img*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
nav li ul{
   display: none;
   position:absolute;
}

nav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

thats all

Comment: ahh. beat me to it! :D gg